# Directional derivatives doubt

Tags: calculus

Why is it the case that when we find directional derivatives in direction of a vector $u$, we have to take into consideration the unit vector? Is there a proof that shows why we need to consider the unit vector? (can't we as well consider the vector $u$ instead that is a scalar multiple of the unit vector?)

Comment: Many authors don't require that $u$ is a unit vector.  The definition $D_u f(x) = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(x + tu) - f(x)}{t}$ makes sense whether or not $u$ is a unit vector.

Comment: If we have $\nabla f$ then $u\cdot\nabla f$ is the directional derivative only if $u$ is a unit vector. Otherwise it's a constant multiple of the derivative.

Comment: You can always use a multiple of a directional derivative, but it's easier if everything is normalized to 1. If you don't do that, then your extra factor propogates itself throughout the problem, maybe becoming squared or witha root, or whatever.  Easier if it is 1.  It's hard enough to get the arithmetic right without extra, unnecessary factors floating around.

Comment: So it's pretty much finding a more "general expression" kind of issue?